# Cleanup after exception

Tags: python, exception

I have a bit of code that resembles the following:

```
try:
    fn()
except ErrorA as e:
    ... do something unique ...
    cleanup()
except ErrorB as e:
    ... do something unique ...
    cleanup()
except ErrorC as e:
    ... do something unique ...
    cleanup()
```

Is there any mechanism in Python that would allow me to call `cleanup` just once, only if an exception is raised? Basically the opposite of `else`.

The best I can think of is:

```
error = True
try:
    fn()
    error = False
except ErrorA as e:
    ... do something unique ...
except ErrorB as e:
    ... do something unique ...
except ErrorC as e:
    ... do something unique ...

if error:
    cleanup()
```

Comment: It's more like the opposite of `else` than the opposite of `finally`.

Comment: You're right. updated.

Comment: @grep Your idea is what I came up with as well.  I don't see another way to do that.

Comment: Looking at the proposed answers, which are all pretty good, my suggestion is to just leave cleanup() redundantly in all methods.  It's a good instance where having redundant code to reduce cognitive complexity is warranted

Answer (score 4):

```
def _cleanup():
    # clean it up
    return

cleanup = _cleanup

try:
    # stuff
except:
    # handle it
else:
    cleanup = lambda: None

cleanup()
```

Answer (score 2):

The most clear way I can think of is do exactly the opposite of `else`:

```
do_cleanup = True
try:
    fn()
except ErrorA as e:
    ... do something unique ...
except ErrorB as e:
    ... do something unique ...
except ErrorC as e:
    ... do something unique ...
else:
   do_cleanup = False

if do_cleanup:
    cleanup()
```

If the code is enclosed and lets itself be done, you can simplify it by returning or breaking in the `else`.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer says do the opposite of `else` but the suggestion propsed by @blcknght seems perfectly good

Answer (score 2):

How about catching all the exceptions with one `except` clause and dividing up the different parts of your handling with `if/elif` blocks:

```
try:
    fn()
except (ErrorA, ErrorB, ErrorC) as e:
    if isinstance(e, ErrorA):
        ... do something unique ...
    elif isinstance(e, ErrorB):
        ... do something unique ...
    else: # isinstance(e, ErrorC)
        ... do something unique ...
    cleanup()
```