# Which is worse - duplicated code or double try/except?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a situation where I want to do multiple things while handling an exception. Since I want to make this about the general case, I'll translate my specific case into some more general language.

When I have an exception in this piece of code, I want to:

1. Always perform a rollback-style operation
2. If it is an
   application specific exception, I want to perform some logging and swallow the exception.

So I can think of two ways to solve it, both ugly:

```py
# Method nested-try/except block
try:
    try:
        do_things()
    except:
        rollback()
        raise
except SpecificException as err:
    do_advanced_logging(err)
    return
```

```py
# Method Duplicate Code
try:
    do_things()
except SpecificException as err:
    rollback()
    do_advanced_logging(err)
    return
except:
    rollback()
    raise
```

Both will have the same behaviour.

I'm tending towards the nested try/except solution myself. While it might be slightly slower, I don't think the speed difference is relevant here - at the very least not for my specific case. Duplication of code is something I want to avoid also because my rollback() statement is slightly more involved that just a database rollback, even if it has the exact same purpose (it involves a web-API).

Is there a third option I haven't spotted that is better? Or is the duplicate code method better? Please note that the rollback() functionality is already factored out as much as possible, but still contains a function call and three arguments which includes a single hardcoded string. Since this string is unique, there's no reason to make it a named constant.

Comment: `raise` needs to `raise SpecificException` in order for it to be caught by the outer try/except

Comment: @Devesh Not if the current exception already is a `SpecificException`…

Comment: So a naked raise rethrows the caught exception? Is that behaviour described anywhere?

Comment: No, raise needs to re-raise any exception it catches, as you should do with any bare except. Only if the exception happens to be a SpecificException do I want that bit - and if it's a SpecificException that triggers the inner except, it will also trigger the outer.

Comment: Yes, that's default Python behaviour.

Comment: @Devesh Sure: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html?highlight=raise#raising-exceptions

Comment: This question looks similar: [Cleanup after exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174116/cleanup-after-exception)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about checking the exception instance type in code?

```
# Method .. No Duplicate Code
try:
    do_things()
except Exception as e:
    rollback()
    if isinstance(e, SpecificException):
        do_advanced_logging(e)
        return
    raise
```

Comment: It would work... but it still itches a bit. I'll accept this if I don't see anything better in the next 24 hours. It's mostly that I don't really like isinstance(). Might be irrational or just me.

Comment: @JaccovanDorp It's just you. ;)

Comment: @JaccovanDorp `except SpecificException as e` is actually doing some typechecking too you know ?-)

Comment: That's different. That's using a net specific to catch that specific type of fish, instead of catching all fish and then sorting them by hand in hopes of finding that specific type of fish. Now, you could call that semantics, you might even be right, but except SpecificException is a lot easier for me to think about than except: if isinstance()...

Answer (score 4):

how about putting the rollback in a `finally` clause?  something like:

```
do_rollback = True
try:
    do_things()
    do_rollback = False
except SpecificException as err:
    do_advanced_logging(err)
finally:
    if do_rollback:
        rollback()
```

an alternative is to use an `else` clause, which would let you do more in the non-exceptional case and not have exceptions all caught in the same place:

```
do_rollback = True
try:
    do_things()
except SpecificException as err:
    do_advanced_logging(err)
else:
    record_success()
    do_rollback = False
finally:
    if do_rollback:
        rollback()
```

is useful when `record_success` can raise a `SpecificException`, but you don't want to `do_advanced_logging`

Answer (score 2):

You could write a context manager:

```
import random

class SpecificException(Exception):
    pass

def do_things(wot=None):
    print("in do_things, wot = {}".format(wot))
    if wot:
        raise wot("test")


def rollback():
    print("rollback")


def do_advance_logging(exc_type, exc_val, traceback):
    print("logging got {} ('{}')".format(exc_type, exc_val))


class rollback_on_error(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, traceback):
        # always rollback
        rollback()
        # log and swallow specific exceptions
        if exc_type and issubclass(exc_type, SpecificException):
            do_advance_logging(exc_type, exc_val, traceback)
            return True
        # propagate other exceptions
        return False


def test():
    try:
        with rollback_on_error():
            do_things(ValueError)
    except Exception as e:
        print("expected ValueError, got '{}'".format(type(e)))
    else:
        print("oops, should have caught a ValueError")

    try:
        with rollback_on_error():
            do_things(SpecificException)
    except Exception as e:
        print("oops, didn't expect exception '{}' here".format(e))
    else:
        print("ok, no exception")


    try:
        with rollback_on_error():
            do_things(None)
    except Exception as e:
        print("oops, didn't expect exception '{}' here".format(e))
    else:
        print("ok, no exception")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

But unless you have dozen occurrences of this pattern, I'd rather stick to the very obvious and perfectly pythonic solutions - either nested exceptions handlers or explicit typecheck (`isinstance`) in the except clause.

Comment: While I appreciate your efforts in writing this answer and it's code, it's a bit overkill in my case at least.

Comment: Yes, obviously - actually I posted it mostly to demonstrate that it was very probably overkill (and that you already had at least to correct, obvious and pythonic solutions).

Comment: What's overkill for me may still be appropriate for other cases, though. And while I'm not sure what google search query could send people here, I think it deserves it's mention.